# SBS 2011: unable to access remote.mydomain.com/myapp after moving from internal to external network

Tags: domain-name-system, website, windows-sbs-2011

I have a secure site setup at remote.mydomain.com, and a webapp at remote.mydomain.com/myapp

Both internal and external clients can access these sites no problem.
However, when a laptop user that can connect internally tries to access the myapp site externally, it fails. The opposite issue happens also.  I assume this is a dns cache issue, as connecting to the server's ip address works (albeit with a security certificate issue).

What's weird is sometimes remote.mydomain.com/myapp won't work, but remote.mydomain.com does!  The browser doesn't seem to make a difference, although most clients use IE9.

I have tried ipconfig /flushdns, it doesn't seem to help.  I haven't tried net stop/start dnscache, but I would really prefer a method that works without any input from the user.

Does anyone have any ideas?  I assume it's a solvable issue since I'm sure many people use remote.mydomain.com/owa internally and externally exactly like this!

Comment: Something in the back of my mind is saying the *browser* has a local DNS cache too (and modern browsers like Chrome play with DNS by doing pre-fetching and so forth). It may be worthwhile ensuring the browser is restarted when moving networks. Alternatively, consider lowering the TTL of those records on internal and external DNS, but be cognisant of the additional traffic consumed in doing that!

Comment: I've settled on a batch files the users have to manually run as administrator when this happens, the batch file does an ipconfig /flushdns and then restarts the dnscache service.  This seems to be working.